# Comparing centrality measures of different graphs

Tags: spatial, graph-theory

I have a set of samples that each containing a certain number of points in 2D. The number of points varies across samples. Each point in these samples also has a specific type, like blue, red, green, etc. I would like to compare the distribution of, say, red points across samples in terms of their clustering and centrality.

I thought about using the centrality scores as introduced by Everett and  Borgatti [The centrality of groups and classes. J. Math. Sociol. 23, 181–201] (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0022250X.1999.9990219). With these, I can get estimates of the centrality and clustering per group (red balls) per sample. However, it is not clear to me how I can compare the centrality and clustering scores calculated per group across samples. Does anyone stumbled upon a similar problem?

To give a bit more background: I have tissue images composed of different cell types. Each image contains different number of cells (a few hundred each) but composed of a subset of cell types. One cell type (A) is present in all samples, and I would like to measure and compare its distribution across images. For instance, I would like to be able to differentiate if these cells of type A are clustered in the image center, or distributed around the periphery etc.

Edit: Thank you all for the comments, suggestions, and the questions. To clarify the question more, I add a depiction of the question (https://imgur.com/a/Er6rSML), which shows two cell types (blue and orange) in a "pocket" (pocket appears to be in 3D but we assume 2D). I have the (x, y) coordinates of all cell centroids (single pixel per cell centroid), but the cells cover on average 50 pixels. Assume that we have multiple independent pockets coming from different images. Then, the questions are how can one determine/measure if orange balls are more clustered in a given pocket and if different pockets have different degree/strength of clustering of the orange balls.

One hypothesis I can test is to compare the distribution of the orange cells in a given pocket to a spatial point process by using Ripley's K. Yet, I get a feeling that the size of the cells should also be somehow included in this analysis, as I have only the centroid locations but the cell areas are much larger than a single pixel.

Comment: In what sense do these cells have a graph structure?  Your description sounds like each type of cell is just a subset of pixels in an image.

Comment: These cells are basically just (x, y) coordinates on an image. The underlying assumption is that cells are potentially interacting with each other based on their distance hence we can construct an undirected graph where edges are the cell locations.

On the other hand, since these are just (x,y) coordinates, I'm also open to solutions that don't use graphs.

Comment: Welcome to cv! If the cells are represented as points in a square, say, you could apply methods for spatial point processes. Since you have a quality attached to them, they would be called marked point processes. With spatial point process statistics, you can also characterize if cells of various types would tend to lie clustered or repel each other, irrespective of where in the image they occur. R has a fantastic package for this kind of analyses, [spatstat](https://spatstat.org/). If this sounds interesting, I can expand :-) - Oh, I just see that you do have (x,y) coordinates!

Comment: Does position relative to the image matter, or can you consider what you see as a small clip from a bigger more or less homogeneous ensemble / tissue?

Comment: @Ute, thank you for the answer. I'm not sure if I correctly understood "the position relative to the image".  I'm only interested in a small section of the tissue (let's call them pockets full of cells) and how these cells are distributed within these pockets.

I'm kinda aware of the spatial point processes. My first idea was to calculate Ripley's K or Moran's I for the areas of interest, but to my understanding these metrics assume that the underlying spatial distribution is a Poisson processes. In my case, the distribution of the cells within these pockets are not necessarily homogenous.

Comment: These indicators, in particular Ripley's K or the closely related pair correlation function, do actually not assume Poisson process, but highlight the difference to the Poisson process. You can see at which range there is interaction between the cells. The usual assumption is that the underlying process is stationary, that is, it does not depend on the image. A situation with pockets that are inhomogeneous would call for the inhomogeneous versions of these statistics. That was what I meant by "position relative to the image" - you seem to want to characterize cells (x,y) with respect to pocket

Comment: "you seem to want to characterize cells (x,y) with respect to pocket": want to characterize the cells within the pocket, only with respect to the pocket.

Comment: @Ute These would be such exceptional, special point processes that I would like to suggest thinking of a different model.  What makes them exceptional is that (1) the locations are on a lattice and (2) every location in the region of interest in the lattice gets some kind of mark.  Presumably these cells are parts of larger organized units, so modeling those units directly would be a more promising approach.  Ripley's K is a good idea, but even before that, basic spatial descriptors (such as the low order multivariate moments) should be employed.

Comment: @whuber, the lattice is just a discretization, but it really depends on the size of the cells in pixels if this matters (much). Without seeing an image of the data I would not recommend anything. From the comments it sounds as if the cells within a pocket are of interest, not some larger context. Ripley's K and the like can be used to show that the points are not Poisson, but the question is if this matters for the research question. One nice variant are the marked Ripley's K and other marked functions that can be used to characterize interaction between points of different colour.

Comment: @Ute The pixels are spatial averages of a continuous process.  Although they *might* be modeled as a marked point process, IMHO it's better to look at models that are more likely to describe the process that produced the image.

Comment: I edited the question to make it (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the image! There are relatively few orange cells...  Ripleys K (for the centroids) is not what you want, sorry for the long discussion here :-).

Comment: @Ute Would Ripleys K be suitable if I wanted to focus on the blue cells? I appreciate the long discussion, it's been informative :)

Comment: Yes, I think so. Also the bivariate versions (comparing one type of cells to another). Ripleys K, or the easier to interpret pair correlation function, can maybe also be used with so few cells, but to get anything reliable out of these, you want to have replicated data sets. One could on the other hand just "misuse" these statistics as something that describes the spatial arrangement, without insisting on estimating a theoretical quantity. You can use them as a statistic for simulation / permutation based tests.

Comment: @ute Indeed, I got some sensible information using the pair correlation functions. I didn't understand the last part of your answer about the "misuse" the statistics, could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: Pair correlation (and K function, and most other summary functions) are defined for stationary, homogeneous point processes. When the patterns are inhomogeneous in density, but otherwise "completely spatial random (no interaction), the summary functions may indicate clustering.

Comment: Alright, it's much clearer to me now. Thank you very much for the discussion.